# Windows IoT Remote Client does not work!

Tags: remote, windows-iot, vnc, virtualization

I would like to access to my Raspberry Pi 3 (running Windows 10 IoT) using Windows IoT Remote Client. The application connect successfully and I can control everything on my PI (mouse and keyboard works fine) but the screen is totally white, so I do not see anything, what I do.
Is there any other way to access to Windows 10 IoT's desktop? (e.g. install vnc server, using TeamViewer)

---

I thought that I install a Linux distribution (e.g. Raspbian) to my Pi and I start somehow a Windows 10 IoT virtual machine. I could reach the Linux OS easily so I can see the virtual Win10IoT OS too. Could it work, or is it a totally bad idea? :D

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

IoT Core version 16299 has a known bug with the Remote Desktop Client on Raspberry Pi devices: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate

According to LAmadio_MSFT in the comments on the page, a fix is in the works and should be released in the (near) future.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Iot version 16299 has an issue with Iot Remote Desktop Client, so you must wait for a newer version of Windows to fix it!

Comment: Do you have a link that documents this?

Comment: Any target date for this expected fix?  Unable to deploy UWP app to a RPI as VS2017 does not connect to it.